# Error creating the managed metadata service: The topology service is not available in the farm

Tags: 2019

I installed 2019 as a Front-end server but want to add Managed Metadata to it. I've changed the role to custom but I'm still getting an error when trying to create the Managed Meta Data Service.

The specific error I'm running into is when I create a Managed Metadata Service I get an error 'Something went wrong. The topology service is not available in the farm.'

Services currently installed:

[image]

Comment: You're not seeing the Service Instances when you go to Manage Services on Server? Is there a reason you want to do this as Search shouldn't run on FEs due to performance reasons.

Comment: is the server showing as custom role? can you see the service from service on server?

Comment: Server is showing as custom role on /_admin/RoleConversion.aspx page. Added Screenshot of services installed.

Comment: The specific error is 'The topology service is not available in the farm.' when creating a Managed Metadata service. Some blog posts say that means some services are not running. How do I figure out which one though?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the role to custom, and using the correct flags to see all services I was able to start the Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service and then was able to create the Managed Metadata service application.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ahmedamin/2017/08/13/the-topology-service-is-not-available-in-the-farm/ had good info to assist.

Get-SPServiceInstance -ALL shows all services

Start-SPServiceInstance InstanceID will start the service.